# compose and upload a new article using a custom form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm starting to learn about php trying to achieve the goal of make my first custom form. From what I understand, it's possible to collect data from a form you can compose and customize to get information like title, subtitle, uploaded images and of course the main text of a supposed post and collect them in an html file that the form itself plus a php file can store in a folder on my server.

what i would like to understand better is if i can compose the form making it be able to include the collected information between pieces of code i don't wanna write anytime in the fields of the form. i also need to understand how to make it be able to save the final html file with a different suffix like an increasing number at the end of the name to be sure no older file created this way is going to be lost cause of overwrite.

the best would be a way to leave the last 5 documents i upload using this method with the suffix between 1 and 5 and rise the number of the older files, but that would be super fancy. doing so i wanna basically make myself a sort of backoffice for my website. I'm sincerely just trying to learn and do it in the most easygoing way so feel free to suggest me good guides if you know some, it would already be a nice help.

Comment: So what is the question exactly? Did you try anything yet? Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] - This website is not a code writing  service

Comment: Hi, Salvatore! Seems like you have a good hold on exactly what you need, which is a great start. Unfortunately, a lot of the things you ask will simply need some good ol' fashioned tinkering, working through tutorials. Highly recommend putting a day aside to build one or two guided tutorial projects!

Comment: i already know how to write a form, i already checked many guides about the argument, but learning everything about it by myself and searching for more specific informations it's getting harder since i don't know enough specific keywords... an example would be awesome of course but even just explication of part of the problem would be useful. and for your information it's not the right place where to flame neither.

Comment: @AndrewCheong i have nobody to guide me but google xD it's not my first form in absolute, i already made many that works sending the information via mail and managed to understand basic guide i found online. with that said i believe i made a clear question and even telling me that it's possible would help.

Comment: To be clear, I haven't downvoted you. Hm. In that case perhaps English isn't your first language. Sorry, but I don't think we understand: _"what i would like to understand better is if i can compose the form making it be able to include the collected informations between pieces of code i don't wanna write anytime in the fields of the form."_

Answer (score 0):

> what i would like to understand better is if i can compose the form
>   making it be able to include the collected informations between pieces
>   of code i don't wanna write anytime in the fields of the form

this is not clear. please give an example.

> i also need to understand how to make it be able to save the final
>   html file with a different suffix

if you really need to save forms data on disk, and avoid collision. you can generate unique id while writing the file as file name
see http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

or using a composer package to generate uuid. see https://github.com/ramsey/uuid
**while i still recommend using a proper data store, database or in memory.**

Comment: example: putting a web address between html tags <a></a>. i'm gonna check your guides but i would like to avoid to relay on a database trying to write every aspect i need in the website by myself.

Comment: @SalvatoreImprota in any case you can retrieve the submitted form data depends on the form method. in case of GET, you have them in super global array $_GET, the same if the form method is POST, then data will be in $_POST and $_FILES - in case your form uploads files.

see http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php
also http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: ty im already finding answers just searching on the php site that google never showed during my research XD (http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)